# Azure pricing : REST API

Tags: azure

Is there any Azure URL from where can download the whole master data with all pricing information?

There is a similar URL in AWS ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/ )
 which gives the full list of pricing data. However could not find one in Azure.

Comment: First hit on google: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview

Comment: I know it a bit late, but this link can help https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/